# Error al hacer push en el servidor remoto de git (bitbucket)

Tags: git, bitbucket

hasta hace poco no había tenido problemas guardando remotamente el proyecto en bitbucket. Anteriormente utilizaba gitlab pero al encontrarme con estos problemas y otros que me habian sucedido con anterioridad decidí migrar a bitbucket, aunque el problema sigue ahí. Este es el siguiente error que me aparece al ejecutar el comando `git push origin master`:

```
Counting objects: 27, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (19/19), done.
fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed (tried to allocate 504819909 bytes)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: write error: Descriptor de archivo erróneo
```

Saludos y gracias de antemano

Comment: Escribe al servicio de ayuda de bitbucket.

Comment: Pero si el problema ocurre también con gitlab no será problema del servidor remoto sino de mi proyecto de git ¿No?

Comment: Estas intentado subir archivos muy grandes, por lo que parece. Deberías intentar evitar ese tipo de archivos.
Te dejo un enlace a SO en ingles con la misma pregunta, por si te sirven alguna de las respuestas:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855317/git-push-out-of-memory-malloc-failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal y como comentabais el problema estaba en el peso de algunos archivos. He añadido unas carpetas con archivos que no eran fundamentales para el funcionamiento del proyecto al gitignore y se ha solucionado.
Gracias.

Comment: eso suele suceder cuando al hacer un push al servidor remoto git no tiene suficiente memoria para hacer la operación, se puede arreglar configurando mas memoria. mira este [git/config file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292903/git-on-windows-out-of-memory-malloc-failed)